# Is it possible to run android emulator / android apps in docker?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, docker

Is it possible to run an android app in a docker container? The app should run a HTTP server, which should be accessible from other containers.

Comment: Please provide reason when downvoting.

Answer (score 8):

Why do you need an android app for running an HTTP server? Can't you just run apache or nginx inside the docker container?

If you want to run android apps on docker, you should look at this.
https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ksoichiro/android-emulator/

Answer (score 6):

Yes, check https://github.com/budtmo/docker-android

all of these devices

[image]